# The name 'Key' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

I am new to Windows app programming. I want to capture the input of a TextBox after a user presses the return key. I keep getting the error "The name 'Key' does not exist in the current context." I have added 'using System.Windows.Input;' but still I get the same error. What am I missing?

```
using App1.Common;
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Basic Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234237

namespace App1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A basic page that provides characteristics common to most applications.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private NavigationHelper navigationHelper;
        private ObservableDictionary defaultViewModel = new ObservableDictionary();

        /// <summary>
        /// This can be changed to a strongly typed view model.
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableDictionary DefaultViewModel
        {
            get { return this.defaultViewModel; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// NavigationHelper is used on each page to aid in navigation and 
        /// process lifetime management
        /// </summary>
        public NavigationHelper NavigationHelper
        {
            get { return this.navigationHelper; }
        }


        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
            this.navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
            this.navigationHelper.SaveState += navigationHelper_SaveState;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Populates the page with content passed during navigation. Any saved state is also
        /// provided when recreating a page from a prior session.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">
        /// The source of the event; typically <see cref="NavigationHelper"/>
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that provides both the navigation parameter passed to
        /// <see cref="Frame.Navigate(Type, Object)"/> when this page was initially requested and
        /// a dictionary of state preserved by this page during an earlier
        /// session. The state will be null the first time a page is visited.</param>
        private void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Preserves state associated with this page in case the application is suspended or the
        /// page is discarded from the navigation cache.  Values must conform to the serialization
        /// requirements of <see cref="SuspensionManager.SessionState"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event; typically <see cref="NavigationHelper"/></param>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that provides an empty dictionary to be populated with
        /// serializable state.</param>
        private void navigationHelper_SaveState(object sender, SaveStateEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region NavigationHelper registration

        /// The methods provided in this section are simply used to allow
        /// NavigationHelper to respond to the page's navigation methods.
        /// 
        /// Page specific logic should be placed in event handlers for the  
        /// <see cref="GridCS.Common.NavigationHelper.LoadState"/>
        /// and <see cref="GridCS.Common.NavigationHelper.SaveState"/>.
        /// The navigation parameter is available in the LoadState method 
        /// in addition to page state preserved during an earlier session.

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        }

        #endregion

        private void Button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            greetingOutput.Text = "Hello, " + nameInput.Text + "!";
        }

        private void item1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Return)
            {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the MSDN library article on the [`KeyRoutedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.keyroutedeventargs.aspx) you will see that the `Key` Property is a [`VirtualKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.virtualkey.aspx) enumeration.  Looking at the enumerations available there is not a <kbd>Return</kbd> but there is an <kbd>Enter</kbd>

> Enter|enter 13  The Enter key.

and in looking the example in the first link you will want something like this

```
if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `KeyRoutedEventArgs`, try using `KeyPressEventArgs` and use like this:

```
private void item1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
        {

        }
    }
```